# REST API: Search products only in the names

Tags: search, rest-api, query-string

I'm using the `WooCommerce REST API` to search products by string.

Quick question: Is it possible to limit the `REST API` query `?search=` to products names ? Currently it also searches the string in the descriptions.

Comment: Are you searching a custom post type named products with the `wp/v2` API or are you searching WooCommerce products using the WooCommerce API? They're different APIs and the WooCommerce one is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm searching WooCoomerce products using the WooCommerce API